# Backbone router not working

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to create a short document router where contents of a document can be accessed by clicking on its title. I wrote the following program using backbone and underscore, but it is not working!

(The program is working to the extent that the title of documents are appearing as a list on the browser)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title> Document Router </title>
<script src= "jquery.js"> </script>
<script src= "underscore.js"> </script>
<script src= "backbone.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<script type= "text/javascript">
    var docs= [
    new Backbone.Model({
        title: 'Javascript Modules', 
        content: ' bbbbbbbbllllllaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhh'
    }),
    new Backbone.Model({
        title: 'Module Systems',
        content: 'Something else'
    })];

    var eventagg= _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

    var conview= Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: 'ul',
        render: function()
        {
            _(this.collection).each(function(document)
            {
      this.$el.append(new doclistv({model: document}).render().el);
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });

    var doclistv= Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: 'li',
        events:
        {
            'click': function()
            {
         eventagg.trigger('document:selected', this.model);
            }
        },

        render: function()
        {
            this.$el.html(this.model.get('title'));
            return this;
        }
    }); 

    var docview= Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        render: function()
        {
      this.$el.append(this.make('h1', null, this.model.get('title')));
   this.$el.append(this.make('div', null, this.model.get('content')));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var docrout= Backbone.Router.extend(
    {
        routes:
        {
            'contents': 'contents',
            'view/:title': 'viewdoc'
        },

        contents: function()
        {
          $('body').html(new conview({collection: docs}).render().el);
        },

        viewdoc: function(title)
        {
           var selecdoc= _(docs).find(function(document)
               {
            return document.get('title')===title;
           });

           $('body').empty().append(
               new docview({model: selecdoc}).render().el);
        }
    });

    var router= new docrout();
    Backbone.history.start();

    eventagg.on('document:selected', function(document)
    {
        var urlpath= 'view/'+ document.get('title');
        router.navigate(urlpath, {trigger: true});
    });

    router.navigate('contents', {trigger: true});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be that the error exists in the following lines (in the definition of docview):

```
    this.$el.append(this.make('h1', null, this.model.get('title')));
    this.$el.append(this.make('div', null, this.model.get('content')));
```

We may replace them with the following, and the program will work just fine:

```
    $('body').append("<h1>"+ this.model.get('title')+ "</h1>");
    $('body').append(this.model.get('content'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `events` in `docview`. Instead of defining the click handler function directly in `events`, write a function that handles the event as a separate attribute of the view and specify the name of the function as a string.

```
var docview = Backbone.View.extend({

    'events': {
        'click': 'onClicked'
    },

    onClicked: function() {
        //app logic
    } 
});
```

See the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View) for more details on how to handle DOM events using jquery selectors in Backbone Views.

Comment: The 'click' event on a "title" triggers an eventagg (in the doclistv variable which extends backbone's view property) which in turn triggers the url routing, is it wrong to apply logic this way?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `var urlpath= 'view/'+ document.get('title');` line,  step through using dev tools and check where the mistake is.